# Can not push to Github: gitmodulesParse: could not parse gitmodules blob

Tags: git, github

After merging several git repositories into on using method from [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/511144). I'm pushing it into Github but it fails with:

```
git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 755, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (518/518), done.
Writing objects: 100% (755/755), 29.91 MiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 755 (delta 195), reused 481 (delta 128)
remote: error: bad config line 1 in blob .gitmodules
remote: error: object b13fc97cca572d71bf5dad31706d4691bb11a1e7: gitmodulesParse: could not parse gitmodules blob
remote: fatal: fsck error in packed object
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To github.com:...........git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:...........git'
```

There was some submodules in some repository which I removed manually (`rm pathtomodule\.git` then `rm .gitmodules`). How to fix it or there are no other way, only remerge? `git fsck --full --strict` gives nothing.

Comment: Please show your `.gitmodules`.

Comment: I didn't find solution to this to my regret. Just dropped git history and started git repository over.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation (also merged repos and the same error). In my case some old commits indeed contained ill-formed `.gitmodules`. Since we don't use submodules in our merged repo and I didn't care to keep even valid `.gitmodules` the way I resolved the problem was to simply remove all `.gitmodules` files from the entire history. Note: this approach effectively rewrites the entire history keeping all commits as is (minus `.gitmodules`) but giving them new hashes.

There is [a utility](https://github.com/nachoparker/git-forget-blob) to do that.

Or, if you want to do it manually (pretty much copied from the utility):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .gitmodules' --force -- --branches --tags
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ .git/refs/remotes/ .git/*_HEAD .git/logs/
(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ || echo :) | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n1 git update-ref -d
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git repack -q -A -d
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```